# Execute dynamically inserted jquery script after the page has already loaded

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm building a page that uses ajax requests to dynamically populate portions of my page.

one of the requests generates an additional jquery script and inserts it into the document.  I cannot figure out how to get the newly added jquery script to run after it is inserted into the page... Any ideas as to how to make this work?

Comment: Use http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/ -- It should run the script after it loads.

Comment: The script i'm inserting is dynamically generated, it isn't static and it doesn't exist anywhere on the server, it's written by the script that's called from the ajax request.    Can that be done with .getScript?

Answer (score 2):

The only way to get scripts to run after the DOM has been parsed, is to add them to the head element:

```
const scriptText = `...`;
const script = document.createElement(`script`);
script.textContent = scriptText;
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

or, in jQuery,

```
const scriptText = `...`;
$(`head`).append($(`<script>${scriptText}</script>`));
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, although why hasn't this type of ability been added, seems rather restrictive.

Comment: It has been? This is it: head insertion means there's one way to insert scripts in a guaranteed executing way. It works in all browsers.